# Does .NET initialize struct padding to zero?

Tags: c#, c++, padding, unmanaged, pack

**When .NET initializes a struct to zero, does it zero out the padding as well?**

I ask because I'm wondering about the limitations of doing bitwise comparisons on unmanaged structs.

Note how `CanCompareBits` not only checks that the type is unmanaged (`!mt->ContainsPointers()`), but also that it is tightly packed (`!mt=>IsNotTightlyPacked`). Mind the double negative on the latter: it requires that the type *is* tightly packed.

```
// Return true if the valuetype does not contain pointer and is tightly packed
FCIMPL1(FC_BOOL_RET, ValueTypeHelper::CanCompareBits, Object* obj)
{
    WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
    STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;

    _ASSERTE(obj != NULL);
    MethodTable* mt = obj->GetMethodTable();
    FC_RETURN_BOOL(!mt->ContainsPointers() && !mt->IsNotTightlyPacked());
}
FCIMPLEND
```

**This code seems to imply that structs with padding are unsuitable for bitwise comparisons. When is this true, and why?**

My assumption is that this has to do with padding initialization, but perhaps there is more going on.

Comment: it could well be that it simply isn't *defined* what should happen re the padding areas in all scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struct padding is explicitly documented as being indeterminant.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code:

> For alignment purposes, there may be unnamed padding at the beginning
> of a struct, within a struct, and at the end of the struct. The
> contents of the bits used as padding are indeterminate.

This matches the documentation for C/C++ structs, which I think is no coincidence. The ISO C99 standard states:

> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type,
> including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation
> that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values."

So to answer your questions:

"When .NET initializes a struct to zero, does it zero out the padding as well?" - Undefined, so you cannot rely on it.

"When is this true?" - Always.

"Why" - If that means "why is the padding not initialised", I can only surmise: Probably for performance reasons, and for compatibility with C/C++ for Interop calls.